# Use HTML element and {{user.userprofile.image.url}} on Submit button Crispy Form

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I hope you're doing well.
Do you know how I can add this to my button:

```
<img src="{{user.userprofile.image.url}}" width="22px" height="22px" style="border-radius: 90px;background: #ffffff38;">
```

I've tried but it's always translated as " Comment" on my page.

```
class CreateCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(CreateCommentForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method="post"
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field("content",css_class="form-control",style="margin-bottom:10px",rows="1"),
        )
        
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit','<img src="{{user.userprofile.image.url}}" width="22px" height="22px" style="border-radius: 90px;background: #ffffff38;"> Comment',css_class="btn btn-sm",style="background-color: #0d6ec5;border-color: #0d6ec5;"))


    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = [
            'content'
        ]
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to add a style to a button on the html template or in the models field?

Comment: I just tried to add the image's user on the submit button

Comment: what is not working, is it the html page or just the image on the button? post the details of your errors.

Comment: By image user you mean?

Comment: I'd like to have image user on my button. Apparently HTML is not working... that's my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to solve two challenges: including dynamic info in the form button (`userprofile.image`), and then having a submit button with an image/HTML content.

1. Including dynamic info in your form: you need to add a kwarg/parameter to your form's `init` method, so that you can pass the user in when you create the form object in your view.
2. Instead of using Crispy's [`Submit`](https://crispy-forms-foundation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout/buttons.html#crispy_forms_foundation.layout.buttons.Submit) button (which creates an `input` element), you should use `StrictButton` instead, which creates a `button` element, and can be filled with whatever HTML you'd like. I'll note that the docs for `StrictButton` are in a weird spot: https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html, separate from the docs on the various buttons. Also worth noting that you could simply use the [`Button`](https://crispy-forms-foundation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout/buttons.html#crispy_forms_foundation.layout.buttons.Button) class in a similar fashion, but the StrictButton class has some frills that make life easier for those using Bootstrap. (Check out [the `crispy_forms.bootstrap` module](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/blob/master/crispy_forms/bootstrap.py#L178) to learn more.)

Here's how I would update your code:

```
# View function:
def my_view(request):
    ...
    comment_form = CreateCommentForm(user=request.user)
    ...


# Forms:
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import StrictButton

class CreateCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # Adding the user kwarg here:
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateCommentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = "post"
        
        # Set up the HTML content for the StrictButton:
        button_content = f'<img src="{user.userprofile.image.url}" width="22px" height="22px" ' \
                         f'style="border-radius: 90px;background: #ffffff38;"> Comment'
                         
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field("content", css_class="form-control", style="margin-bottom:10px", rows="1"),
            
            # Add the button to the layout:
            StrictButton(button_content, type='submit', css_class='btn btn-primary btn-block', id='save'),
        )

    ...
```

Comment: You bet! I use this pattern frequently - initializing the form with a particular value, so that the form's contents can be altered dynamically, in the `init` method. A contrived example would be a situation where you want to make one field's choices dependent upon the value of another field. Something like: "If the user's Favorite_Sport is baseball, then populate the choices for Favorite_Team with baseball teams". Best wishes with your project! :)